# Update sql actualizar fecha de baja de unos registros con la fecha de alta de su ultimo registro

Tags: mysql, script, update

Estoy añadiendo dos columnas nuevas a una tabla, donde creo el campo fecha de baja y activo a una tabla ya existente y con datos. Ya tengo las columnas creadas pero para que tenga sentido tengo que realizar un script que me actualice los registros. Ya tengo realizado el que me activa los registros, pero con el de la fecha de baja no sé como puedo realizarlo.
Solo puedo tener un registro activo en un id_aval, por lo tanto tengo que actualizar las fecha de bajas de los registros que no estén activos con la fecha de alta de su registro activo.
Os facilito el update que estoy intentando realizar.

```
UPDATE tabla
SET
    activo =(
        SELECT
            fecha_alta, id_aval
        FROM
           tabla 
        WHERE
            ( id_aval,
              fecha_alta ) IN (
                SELECT
                    id_aval,
                    MAX(fecha_alta)
                FROM
                   tabla
                GROUP BY
                    id_aval
            )
        GROUP BY
            id_aval
    ) where activo=0;
```

Actualmente me salta un error de no es un expresión group by, me podéis echar una mano, no me queda muy claro como puedo realizarlo. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Una pregunta me estas diciendo que los datos están en otra tabla porque de ser asi se puede solucionar con un ``INSERT INTO tabla SELECT DATOS1,DATOS2 FROM Tabla1;`` Y seria mucho mas fácil

Comment: Estan en la misma tabla todos, el id_aval, fecha_alta, fecha_baja y activo pertenecen todos a la misma tabla "tabla" pongo tabla por no dar en nombre en especifico por seguridad.

Comment: Pero esos datos de esas dos columnas nuevas se encuentran en otra tabla?

Comment: No, todo esta en la misma tabla. Las fecha de baja unicamente las tengo que informar en los registros que no esten activos, con la fecha de alta del registro que tenga el mismo id_aval

Comment: A ver si me explico me refiero que si los datos que quieres actualizar se encuentra en otra tabla

Comment: la tabla es la misma, te respondo en el comentario anterior a tu pregunta. Las columnas de la tabla son ID (PK de la tabla), id_Aval, id_x, id_a, codigo_x, usuario_alta, fecha_Alta, fecha_baja y activo.

Comment: vale muchas gracias